# Topusers: add total number of votes, total number of answers

Tags: feature-request, top-users

In the beginning of the [topuser-page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/top-users/topusers) the total number of questions and their percentage is given.

What is missing here is the total number of votes (total, last 30, last 7 days)
and also the total number of answers (total, last 30, last 7 days).

It probably does not make much sense to distinguish between up- and downvotes.

These numbers are particularly useful for smaller tags, where it is difficult to estimate the actual size of the tag.

The area for this information is located in the picture below, labeled void:

[image: Location of empty area]

Comment: I'd like this. I think it would be very nice :).